# Get random port for UDP socket

Tags: c, sockets

I need to create a program that will communicate with other programs on the same computer via UDP sockets. It will read commands from `stdin`, and some of this commands will make it to send/receive packets without halting execution. I've read some information out there, but since I'm not familiar with socket programming and need to get this done quickly, I have the following questions:

1. I need to get a random unused port for the program to listen to, and reserve it so other programs can communicate with this and also the port isn't reserved by another program. I also need to store the port number on a variable for future usage.
2. Since the communication is across processes on the same machine, I'm wondering if I can use PF_LOCAL.

Also a code sample of the setup of such socket would be welcome, as well as an example of sending/receiving character strings.

Comment: Linux OS using standar libraries

Comment: Why communicate between processes using a socket? Is it just for the sake of doin' it? ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Call `bind()` specifying port 0.  That will allow the OS to pick an unused port.  You can then use `getsockname()` to retreive the chosen port.

Comment: This is a good way to do it but it certainly wouldn't be a random way of doing it.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted a truly random port, you could keep trying to bind to ((rand()%65535)+1) until bind returns success.

Comment: It will be random in that you will not know what port is chosen until the binding is successful.  Binding to port 0 allows the OS to pick the first available unused port.  If `bind()` succeeds, you are guarateed to have a port that is only being used by you and nobody else.  Your stated requirements do not require it to be truely random persay, just unique, and it will be.

Comment: I think the port returned by bind(.., 0) is not so good for persistent usage; see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Remy Lebeau is good if you need a temporary port. It is not so good if you need a persistent reserved port because other software also uses the same method to get a port (including OS TCP stack that needs a new temporary port for each connection).

So the following might happen:

1. You call bind with 0 and getsockname() to get a port;
2. then save it into config (or into several configs) for future uses;
3. software that needs this port starts and binds the port.

Then you need to e.g. restart the software:

1. software stops and unbinds the port: the port can now be returned by bind(0) and getsockname() again;
2. e.g. TCP stack needs a port and binds your port;
3. software can't start because port is already bound.

So for "future uses" you need a port that is not in ephemeral port range (that's the range from which bind(host, 0) returns a port).

My solution for this issue is the [port-for](https://github.com/kmike/port-for/) command-line utility.

Comment: Very rarely, if ever, will you need to retreive an ephemeral port the first time and save it for re-use in subsequent connections.  I've been writing socket code for over 10 years and have never needed to do that, not once. Typically, you would either use ephemeral ports every time (and for servers, provide a way of discovering that port dynamically), or have the user specify a fixed port in your app's configuration, in which case the user ensures the port is always available for use.

Comment: If my understanding of the question is correct (esp. "1" part), it asks for this. This may not be the case though. The use case is not to make user ensure the port is always available but to make a software ensure the port is available.

Answer (score 0):

If it being a random port is actually important, you should do something like:

```
srand(time(NULL));
rand() % NUM_PORTS; // NUM_PORTS isn't a system #define
```

Then specify that port in bind. If it fails, pick a new one (no need to re-seed the random generator. If the random port isn't important, look at Remy Lebeau's answer.

Comment: You would have to keep track of which ports you attempted so you do not try to bind to them again since they failed the first time.

Comment: True, although the likelihood that you'd repeat ports in the pseudo-random sequence before finding an open port is pretty low.