# Generate port number at runtime in Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, sockets

Is there any way to generate an available `port number` at run time of a program without hard coding a value in a file. (in linux)

Task: I'm writing a Ruby program which creates a socket listener. If I hard coded the value, I will not be able to create more than one instances of the program at a time.

Note: The server is creating the client process. So it's possible to send the server port to the client at run time. So client knows the server port.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842404/get-random-port-for-udp-socket answers that.

Comment: Listening on a random port makes no sense. Clients must know the number to connect. Take the number from command-line arguments, and have a default value.

Comment: Use a [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) ie `AF_UNIX` socket. You need a random path name, e.g. [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html). If you use a TCP socket, your remote client needs to know the port.

Comment: Thank you all. @basile: the client process will be generated by the server process. So I can send the server port to the client as an argument. Then is there any mechanism to find an available TCP port in linux?

Comment: "the client process will be generated by the server process" -- prefer Unix domain sockets. If you for some reason need TCP, read the answers linked in the previous comments.